# Clang with C code: enumeration values not explicitly handled in switch

Tags: c, enums, clang, suppress-warnings

I'm trying to compile this code with clang 3.1 and the option `-Weverything`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

SDL_Surface* init(SDL_Surface* screen);


int main() {
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;
    int quit = 0;

    screen = init(screen);
    if (screen == NULL) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while(quit == 0) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT ) {
                quit = 1;
            } else if( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN ) {
                switch( event.key.keysym.sym ) {
                    case SDLK_UP: printf("up\n"); break;
                    case SDLK_DOWN: printf("down\n"); break;
                    case SDLK_LEFT: printf("left\n"); break;
                    case SDLK_RIGHT: printf("right\n"); break;
                    default: break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(screen);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

SDL_Surface* init(SDL_Surface* screen) {
    if( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1) {
        return NULL;
    }
    screen=SDL_SetVideoMode(100,100,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);
    return screen;
}
```

The compiler then returns me the following warning

```
main.c:22:25: warning: 229 enumeration values not explicitly handled in switch: 'SDLK_UNKNOWN', 'SDLK_BACKSPACE',
      'SDLK_TAB'... [-Wswitch-enum]
                switch( event.key.keysym.sym ) {
                        ^
```

Elsewhere I've read similar error messages and people solved it by adding the `default` case, but here as you can see it's already there. I would really like to compile my code without a single warning, and of course here without needing to put the 229 possible cases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407282/xcode-vs-visual-studio-sdl-c , as the guy is using Xcode, I guess the compiler behind is clang, but it's true he didn't precise which options he was using.

Comment: For some use cases one can achieve better code quality with macros that define an action and a name for every enumerator; this may be one of them if indeed the goal is to print the enumerator name. I have written [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68361006/3150802) for a similar C++ question. Of course, writing 229 entries is still tedious and perhaps prohibitive, but at least it doesn't clutter your actual code, and the method guards against future added enumerators.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From this link:

http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Question-on-Wswitch-enum-td4025927.html

compile with (see comments for possible change) `-Weverything -Wno-switch-enum`

Docs for GCC: 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

-Wswitch
Warn whenever a switch statement has an index of enumerated type and lacks a
case for one or more of the named codes of that enumeration. (The presence of a
default label prevents this warning.) case labels outside the enumeration range
also provoke warnings when this option is used (even if there is a default
label). This warning is enabled by -Wall.

-Wswitch-enum
Warn whenever a switch statement has an index of enumerated type and lacks a
case for one or more of the named codes of that enumeration. case labels
outside the enumeration range also provoke warnings when this option is used.

> > > The only difference between -Wswitch and this option is that this option
> > >       gives a warning about an omitted enumeration code even if there is a default
> > >       label.<<<

Comment: I just tried this today and `-Wno-switch-enum` didn't work, but `-Wno-switch` did the trick.  I guess it has been changed up a bit.

Comment: I tried both `-Wno-switch-enum` and `-Wno-switch`, but none of them worked.

Comment: @DonaldDuck what compiler and version?  Link to a godbolt example if you can please.

Comment: @xaxxon The compiler is Android Clang (C++, arm, NDK 21.3.6528147). [Here](https://pastebin.com/0RJ5CP2Y) is a simple example that gives that warning even with both `-Wno-switch-enum` and `-Wno-switch`.

Comment: @DonaldDuck if you post the example here you can actually show the error happening.   https://godbolt.org/

Comment: @xaxxon It seems like the problem is that my IDE is passing `-Wall`, so the command it runs is basically `clang++.exe main.cpp -Wno-switch-enum -Wno-switch -Wall`. I can't stop it from passing `-Wall` though, and I can't either control the order in which it passes the arguments. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: @DonaldDuck my understanding is the flags are processed in order left to right.   If you turn on all warnings then turn them off, you're good.. but then if you -Wall again, that would turn them back on.   So the flags to turn them off just have to be after the flags to turn them on.